# WPF TextBlock BackGround not being set using style

Tags: wpf, textblock

I am learing WPF. I was trying to apply `Background` and `Foreground` for a `TextBlock` using `Style.Trigger`. From my defined `Trigger`, I can notice the Foreground being changed on `MouseOver`, but not `Background`. Can you please help. Below is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.ApplyingStyle"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ApplyingStyle"
        Height="300"
        Width="300">
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="myStyle">
      <Setter Property="Control.Background"
              Value="Red" />
      <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily"
              Value="Times New Roman" />
      <Setter Property="Control.FontSize"
              Value="25" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver"
                 Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Control.Foreground"
                  Value="HotPink" />
          <Setter Property="Control.Background"
                  Value="Blue" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition   Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Name="myTextBlock"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Style="{StaticResource myStyle}">Hello</TextBlock>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the control Type that you are trying to apply the Style to in your Style Declaration, instead of using `Control.Background` use `TextBlock.Background` or just set the `TargetType` to `TextBlock`. It appears to work when I set your style to something like this.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.ApplyingStyle"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ApplyingStyle" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Times New Roman" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"  >
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="HotPink" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid ShowGridLines="True" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition   Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Name="myTextBlock"  
                   Grid.Row="1" 
                   Grid.Column="0" 
                   Style="{StaticResource myStyle}">Hello</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I tried doing that but no effect. Is there something obvious that I am missing.

Comment: @NainilPatel it is working with your example code for me. Also I made an edit see if it works now. I just posted your example that I modified with the changes. This does work.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `Style.TargetType`, this allows to

1. Shorten the `Setter.Property` values
2. Prevent ambiguity between normal properties and attached properties
3. Get some IDE validation if the target type actually has that property

`TextBlock` is *not* a `Control` which is why this won't work. Either use `TargetType="TextBlock"` and change `Control.Background` to `Background` or use `TextBlock.Background`.

(When working with styles also watch out for [value precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), if you set the `Background` on the `TextBlock` itself you have a **local value** which overrides the style completely)